# Android: LIAC bluetooth how to

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

Does anyone have any idea about how i can use LIAC Limited Inquiry Access Code (Bluetooth) on Android? There are any libraries or similar that can be used for resolving this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I came across this discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-developers/browse_thread/thread/514dd5336d4e1f44 can anyone explain me how to [cit:] "You can build bluecove-android2 from source 
http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/source/checkout" ?